# Rolling Data Source and Appending to PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a rather unique problem that I was hoping that the community could help me out with. Currently I have a data source that will only store up to 6 months of data, and with every new month it will be replaced with a new month data, while the old data will be erased. This is simply the limitation of our enterprise BI tools as it exports csv and anything more than 6 months data exceeds the row limit in any csv format (or rather any excel format for that matter).

That being said, I am searching for a solution where I can import the data into powerBI and use it as an archive, so I will to be able to append the data rather than replacing them every month.

Data source example as attached.

Jun-22 Data
| Date | Name | Sales |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
|31-Jan-22| Kent| 793|
|31-Jan-22| Barbie| 592|
|28-Feb-22| Kent    | 422|
|28-Feb-22| Barbie| 699|
|31-Mar-22| Kent|   687|
|31-Mar-22| Barbie| 493|
|30-Apr-22| Kent|   593|
|30-Apr-22| Barbie| 611|
|31-May-22| Kent|   715|
|31-May-22| Barbie| 648|
|30-Jun-22| Kent|   677|
|30-Jun-22| Barbie| 757|

Jul-22 Data
| Date | Name | Sales |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
|28-Feb-22| Kent    | 422|
|28-Feb-22| Barbie| 699|
|31-Mar-22| Kent|   687|
|31-Mar-22| Barbie| 493|
|30-Apr-22| Kent|   593|
|30-Apr-22| Barbie| 611|
|31-May-22| Kent|   715|
|31-May-22| Barbie| 648|
|30-Jun-22| Kent|   677|
|30-Jun-22| Barbie| 757|
|31-Jul-22| Kent|   563|
|31-Jul-22| Barbie| 485|

Desired Outcome when I refresh in Jul-22 Data

| Date | Name | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31-Jan-22 | Kent | 793 |
| 31-Jan-22 | Barbie | 592 |
| 28-Feb-22 | Kent | 422 |
| 28-Feb-22 | Barbie | 699 |
| 31-Mar-22 | Kent | 687 |
| 31-Mar-22 | Barbie | 493 |
| 30-Apr-22 | Kent | 593 |
| 30-Apr-22 | Barbie | 611 |
| 31-May-22 | Kent | 715 |
| 31-May-22 | Barbie | 648 |
| 30-Jun-22 | Kent | 677 |
| 30-Jun-22 | Barbie | 757 |
| 31-Jul-22 | Kent | 563 |
| 31-Jul-22 | Barbie | 485 |

Based on my understanding of how Power BI works, I might need to first "copy" this data to a static table in Power BI, and then append the data data somehow, but I lack the technical knowhow to do it. Was wondering if any gurus out here can help me out?